# UI Testing: accessibilityIdentifier is set and detected by accessibilityInspector but not by recorder

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcuitest

This issue occurs when using a different iPhone version.

Using iPhone 5 and recorder:

```
app.scrollViews.otherElements.collectionViews.staticText[“TEXT”]
```

Using iPhone 7 and recorder:

```
app.children(matching: .window).element(boundBy: 0).children(matching: .other).element(boundBy: 1).scrollViews.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .collectionView).element.children(matching: .cell).element(boundBy: 0).children(matching: .other).element(boundBy: 0)`
```

Tests breaks because It couldn't locate the element when testing on iPhone 7, although using accessibilityInspector on iPhone 7 will state that the accessibilityValue is "TEXT"

Comment: You can't query for an element using its `accessibilityValue` - only its `accessibilityIdentifier`, `accessibilityLabel` or `text`.
The same query should work on an iPhone 5 and iPhone 7 so if one is working, use that.

Comment: Sorry, It's the accessibilityIdentifier.

Comment: @Oletha got confused for a sec, but "TEXT" is the value that appears on the accessibility inspector.